# Jquery plugin return to caller when ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

My title might be a bit unclear. For example I have this code:

```
$('#element').image_resize_crop();
```

At a certain point the image_resize_crop plugin I'm writing is finished preloading an image. How do I return that to the script that called the function in the first place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either `trigger` a custom event which they can subscribe to and execute code,

```
$(elem).trigger('preloadComplete');
```

and they can use it

```
$('#element').on('preloadComplete',function(){
    // do what they want
})
```

or receive a `oncomplete` handler as setting of the plugin like this

```
$('#element').image_resize_crop(function(){

});
```

Or as part of settings object

```
$('#element').image_resize_crop({
     onComplete: function(){

     }
});
```

And if you want to pass some data to that callback you can instruct them so like this

```
$('#element').image_resize_crop({
     onComplete: function(data){
       // utilize data passed from plugin
     }
});
```

And call that function when image preloading is complete.

In your plugin code you can call it like

```
settings.onComplete.call(this,arg1,arg2);
```

Where `this` is what that `onComplete` function will get as `this` variable inside it, and arg1,arg2 are the values it will get as arguments.

You can use `apply` method too.

Read more here: [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Joy, so I pass the onComplete attribute to the image_resize_crop function. Then in the plugin, how do I initiate it?